# Erratic behavior of ListView CheckBoxes when drag-selecting

Tags: .net, winforms

I have a `ListView` on a Form with `Checkbox`es enabled. Here's a simple example program:

```
[STAThread]
static void Main ()
{
    var form = new Form();
    var listView = new ListView() {
        Dock = DockStyle.Fill, CheckBoxes = true, View = View.List };
    listView.Items.Add("a");
    listView.Items.Add("b");
    listView.Items.Add("c");
    form.Controls.Add(listView);
    Application.Run(form);
}
```

If you run this program, try **drag-selecting** two or three `ListView` items. This works fine. But now try again and "accidentally" release your mouse button on top of a `CheckBox`.

The result is that the `CheckBox` below the mouse cursor itself isn't affected, but all the other selected items get checked/unchecked depending on the state of that one `CheckBox`. End-users find this behavior erratic, and I agree.

Is there a simple way to suppress such accidental `CheckBox` changes when drag-selecting `ListView` items?

Comment: +1 for actually posting a complete program that anyone can just copy-and-paste to run! Not to mention... this is *very* interesting.

Answer (score 0):

You may try [Better ListView Express](http://www.componentowl.com/better-listview-express) - it is free, rewritten in managed code and quite mature control.

The check boxes behavior and other glitches of regular .NET ListView are fixed here. For example, the check boxes are fully animated (hot and pressed states) and you can even have radio buttons...

The control can be used even commercially. There is also a [full version](http://www.componentowl.com/better-listview) which supports also three-state check boxes.

The check boxes are supported in every view, not only Details.

[image]